# Rails uniqueness validation test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing, unique

I'm starting out with Rails 4.2, and I'm try to test uniqueness for the Item models I'm making, I ran this code:

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
    validates :name, uniqueness: true #, other validations...
end
```

item_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup
        @item = Item.new(name: "Example Item")
    end

    test "name should be unique" do
        duplicate_item = @item.dup
        @item.save
        assert_not duplicate_item.valid?
    end
end
```

but the test didn't pass, saying that the `assert_not` line is coming out `true` when it should be `nil` or `false`. I basically got this code from a tutorial but cannot figure out why it's not passing. Any help?

**Edit**: I found the solution, by not defining the other members (specifically `:price` ) of `@item` that I defined in the `setup` action, the test passed. However now I don't know how to make it pass with the the `:price` member. Below is the full implementation of item.rb & item_test.rb.

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name, :description, :price
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
    validates :description, presence: true,
        length: { maximum: 1000 }
    VALID_PRICE_REGEX = /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/
    validates :price, presence: true,
        :format => { with: VALID_PRICE_REGEX },
        :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
end
```

item_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup
        @item = Item.new(name: "Example Item", description: "Some kind of item.", price: 1.00)
    end

    test "name should be unique" do
        duplicate_item = @item.dup
        @item.save
        assert_not duplicate_item.valid?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I got rid of the `attr_accessor` line, the test was then able to access the attributes and was able to detect the duplication.

Answer (score 5):

Almaron's answer above is correct and should be the accepted answer.

I am adding this answer to elaborate on it.

The test would be as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @item = Item.create(name: "Example Item")
  end

  test "name should be unique" do
    duplicate_item = @item.dup
    assert_not duplicate_item.valid?
  end
end
```

Note: `duplicate_item` need not be saved before validating it.

Comment: Neither answer made any changes, although when I got rid of all my other members of the object it worked. The problem now is I'm not sure how to validate it and keep the other members. I've updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

The uniqueness validation is performed against the records already existing in the database. And your `Item.new(name: "Example Item")` is not in the database untill it is saved. So if you use `Item.create(name: "Example Item")` instead, the test should pass.

Comment: That didn't make any changes, although when I got rid of all my other members of the object it worked. The problem now is I'm not sure how to validate it and keep the other members. I've updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You've identified at least some of the problem in your edit.

The problem isn't that you're using `Item.new` instead of `Item.create` the problem is that when you do `@item.save` the @item record isn't being saved because it has other validation issues.

You could try...

```
@item.save(validate: false)
```

... which will force `@item` to be written to the database, but the test doesn't really determine why the `duplicate_item` record is invalid.

Better might be to test that you have an error relating to `name`...

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @item = Item.new(name: "Example Item")
  end

  test "name should be unique" do
    duplicate_item = @item.dup
    @item.save(validate: false)
    duplicate_item.valid? # need this to populate errors
    assert duplicate_item.errors
    assert duplicate_item.errors[:name]
  end
end
```

Comment: You're onto something, your two asserts come back as true, but when I use `Rails::logger.debug` and check the test log for `assert duplicate_item.errors.full_messages` it came back as an empty array

Comment: You did `duplicate_item.valid?` before the assertion? It will have no errors until you test for validity.